# How do I validate that specific columns with the respective datatype in my Polars DataFrame exist?

Tags: python, validation, python-polars

I want to validate that specific columns with their datatypes exist in a given Polars DataFrame. The Polars DataFrame may have additional columns. I am aware of [Patito](https://patito.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for polars data validation. But unfortunately I could not find a methode to validate that my required columns with their datatypes exist. With additional columns in the DataFrame a **ValidationError** is raised due to Superflous columns:

```
import polars as pl
import patito as pt


class model(pt.Model):
    name: str
    age: int

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Peter", "Anna", "Tyler"],
        "age": [29, 18, 49],
        "location": ["Chicago", "Paris", "Singapur"],
    }

model.validate(df) #raises ValidationError due to superflous column "location"
```

If that would be possible with `patito`, how do I validate column names with spaces and hyphens e.g. "column 1" or "column-1"?

**Edit 1**
for further explanation regarding the additional question.

```
import polars as pl
import patito as pt


class model(pt.Model):
    name: str
    column-1: int #won't work since variable names only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Peter", "Anna", "Tyler"],
        "column-1": [29, 18, 49],
        "location": ["Chicago", "Paris", "Singapur"],
    }

model.validate(df) #raises ValidationError due to superflous column "location"
```

Comment: Are you asking for a `patito` only solution? Or can you `assert` against a `df.schema.items()` existence check?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a `patito` solution, but it would be nice to use the dummy-data functionality of `patito`.

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure your df has the minimum required columns while ignoring extras AND that the required columns don't need an exact name so that 'column 1' counts as 'column-1'

Comment: I edited my question. I would like to ensure that the polars dataframe has the required columns including the respective required datatypes. If that would be possible with `patito` how would I implement the schema in `class model(pt.Model)` if the column names of the polar dataframe contain spaces or hyphens.

Comment: could you further elaborate on what you want to happen with the superfluous columns? It seems you're saying you want to ignore that error. Is that right?

Comment: maybe a better way to say that is you don't want it to raise when the df has extra columns. Am I understanding your intention correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are two issues.

#### How to create a model with fields that python doesn't allow as class elements

To do that, you rely on `Field`'s `alias` parameter

You'd do

```
class model(pt.Model):
    name: str
    column1_or_any_allowable_name: int = pt.Field(alias='column-1')
```

#### How to have the model validation ignore extra columns

It doesn't seem there's a direct way to do this but instead you can use the model properties to `select` the relevant columns like this

```
model.validate(df.select(model.schema()['required']))
```

If there's a field in the model that doesn't exist as a column in the `df` then polars will raise `ColumnNotFoundError` which is not the same as `ValidationError` so if you're using a `try` `except ValidationError` you'd have to include the `except ColumnNotFoundError` to that as well.